# Можно ли работать с консолью MySQL в сборке Denwer?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Можно ли работать с консолью *MySQL* в сборке Denwer? 
Если нет, то можно ли поставить две версии *MySQL* на компьютер, но чтобы они обе работали с *phpmyadmin*? При этом хотя бы чтобы с одной можно было работать через консоль? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы полноценно работать с MySQL в консоли, нужно просто запустить клиент mysql из командной строки. Проверить не могу, так как нет Windows под рукой, но быстрое гугление показывает, что искомый файл в инсталляции денвера должен лежать в `/usr/local/mysql-5.1` или `/usr/local/mysql-5.5` в зависимости от версии.

Внутри phpmyadmin, который в состав денвера входит и работает там из коробки, есть веб-консоль, в которой можно писать запросы.

Что касается второй части вопроса - установить на компьютер можно сколько угодно версий MySQL (по разным путям), но не очень понятно, зачем это конкретно Вам и при чём тут phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Открываем обычную командную строку в Windows `cmd.exe`. Далее пишем `mysql -u root -p`. После этого будет предложено ввести пароль. По умолчанию в денвере он пустой. Поэтому просто жмем `enter`.

Если же скажет что `mysql` не найден, то нужно прописать путь в переменные среды.

Comment: ...или предварительно сделать `cd` в папку, где лежит exe-шник mysql